# Error After Selecting dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

When I make selection in dataTable it gives error below

```
[javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or you need to define rowKey attribute]]
```

But in my dataTable rowKey attribute is already define and I checked it's value is unique. What could be the possible reason I am getting this error

DataTable code is as below

```
<p:dataTable id="scenarioDataTableId" var="scenarioDataTable" value="#{myBean.scenarioApplicationColumnBOList}" tableStyle="width:90%" rowKey="scenarioDataTable.scenarioApplicationColumnId" selection="#{myBean.selectedScenarioApplicationColumnRow}" >
    <f:facet name="header">Database Columns That will be updated in this Scenario</f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" listener="#{myBean.editSelectedScenarioApplicationColumnAction}"></p:ajax>
    <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:10%" /> 

    <p:column id="Id" headerText="Id" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.scenarioApplicationColumnId}
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="scenarioId" headerText="Scenario Id" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.scenarioId}
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="appId" headerText="Application Column Id" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.applicationColumnId}
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="tableNameId" headerText="Table Name" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.tableName}
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="columnNameId" headerText="Column Name" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.columnName}
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="columnValidValueId" headerText="Column Valid Value" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.columnValidValue}
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="dbActionId" headerText="DB Action" >
                            #{scenarioDataTable.dbAction}
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Add New Row" action="#{myBean.openDialogScenarioUpdateColumn}" oncomplete="dialogScenarioUpdateColumn.show()" rendered="#{myBean.scenarioInputFieldRendered}"></p:commandButton>    
        <p:spacer width="20" ></p:spacer>
        <p:commandButton id="editButton" value="Edit" action="#{myBean.editSelectedScenarioApplicationColumnAction}" update=":formSelectCriteria:ScenarioMainPanel" ></p:commandButton>
        <p:spacer width="20" ></p:spacer>
        <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" value="Delete"></p:commandButton>
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf). A `rowKey` must refer to an attribute shown in your `p:dataTable` (which is an attribute of one of your `#{myBean.scenarioApplicationColumnBOList}` objects), e.g.

```
rowKey="#{scenarioDataTable.scenarioApplicationColumnId}"
```

but not

```
rowKey="scenarioDataTable.scenarioApplicationColumnId"
```

Comment: oh..silly mistake. You know I was breaking my head for entire day. Anyway Thanks for pointing the error